# Raspbian autostart fails, but .desktop file works on click

Tags: python, raspberry-pi, gnome, raspbian, kde-plasma

I have a .desktop file on `~/.config/autostart` that runs a python script.
When I execute the file by myself it works fine, but it don't starts on IDE initialization.

The file structure seems ok, I've tried a lot of changes on the `.desktop` file and nothing worked.

*Is there any way to discovery what error is occurring on the initialization?*

Comment: The problem don't seems to be on the autostart script, if I change Exec to any other application, like chromium, it starts. Like I said, if I double click on the .desktop file, it starts.

Comment: 1. What is Exec? 2. What does the file look like? 3. What is the connection between the Desktop file and an autostart script. I do not see any.

Comment: On KDE and GNOME enviroments, I can create a file with the .desktop extension to easily upstart a application. This is the standards to create that file http://bit.ly/1xobONi. The enviroment also have an autostart directory. Any .desktop file I put in this directory starts when the user interface start. I've tagged like raspbian and python because I'm convinced that the problem is some particularity about them, it only don't works on my Raspberry Pi. The problem is get the error message. I've not found any log. If some line have an error, how can I discovery on what line it is?